# Calculating work in an Image dipole method

Tags: electromagnetism, work, inertial-frames, dipole, method-of-images

I have encountered an Electromagnetism problem, which asked me to calculate the total work required to separate an electric dipole from a conducting plane.

The dipole's moment was given $p$ and the angle between the dipole moment vector and the normal of the plane was given $\theta$.

Here, we can use the method of Image Charges and consider an image dipole below the surface. The image is from Wikipedia but identical to the current setup.

[image]

It further goes that knowing the potential energy is $U = - p \cdot E$, we can calculate the work required to separate the two dipoles to $+ \infty$ and $-\infty$ and denote the work $W$. Of course, $E$ is the electric field produced by the image dipole.

More precisely, $$W = - \Delta U = - \int _{2a} ^{+\infty}(dU/dr) dr$$

Here is the problem.

The solution says, since the lower image dipole is not actually moving, the work required to remove the upper (real) dipole to infinity is $W/2$. But I don't understand this. Thinking an analogy of similar cases, we don't say if we remove a ball from the earth, it takes half the gravitational energy(its magnitude) because the earth is not moving!

Similarly, I think if the potential energy depends only on the distance between two objects, it shouldn't matter on which point of reference we view the system. It doesn't make sense if we look at the midpoint of the two dipoles we measure $W$, but if we lock our position onto one of the dipoles, suddenly the work drops to half even though the situation hasn't changed (and I guess both are inertial reference frames since we can separate them at constant speeds).

Is there any misunderstanding in my point of view? Does the work really change for different inertial systems?